# BreezeJS with a Linux backend

Tags: breeze

I am working on a project where we have a very slim server (Linux, Nginx, Sqlite), but our web application shall not show any signs of shortcomings (should contain charts, dashboards, nice looking controls) – so I need the client to do all the heavy work.
I assume that BreezeJS would be good in this case, because it manages data on the client, in a way that reduces workload on the server. The server only sends the data to the client and at some point gets data back that has to be saved to the database. All caching and other stuff is managed on the client.
I assume AngularJS would also be good in this case, because it is a client-side MVC-framework, again reducing workload on the server. It also works seamlessly together with BreezeJS.
I assume Wijmo would also be good in this case, because it provides nice looking controls and also works seamlessly together with BreezeJS and AngularJS.
Are my assumptions right? Any comments?
My only concerns are how I get BreezeJS to “talk” with the Linux-server (Nginx, Sqlite). Are there any samples regarding this? Is anyone working on something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will be releasing a NodeJS/Express/Mongo example within the next few weeks that should show how to communicate with an arbitrary non-.NET backend.  (also see the current 'Edmunds' example in the Breeze zip).  But we don't have anything yet that explicity shows Breeze working with a Linux backend.  Please vote for this here: [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions)